# Error trying to use date-fns package in express

Tags: node.js, express, date-fns

I am trying to use the package `date-fns` within my node express app but unsure how to "require" it. I have tried:

```
const format =  require("date-fns");
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: format is not a function
```

Comment: try `const {format} = require("date-fns")`

Comment: all good. I also had to include `const { format, parseISO } =  require("date-fns");`

Comment: @boxdox - can you pls add your response as the answer to this question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no default export in the library. `format` is a named export, use
this syntax:

```
const {format} = require("date-fns")
```